# Insert values using select query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried lot to achieve this but no luck. Let me explain
I have table A and moving the data to another called table B, while moving I need to update col2 values, when table A col1 equal to col3 then update col2 = col3(Matching column col3). if values is not found then we need to search next row, if values is matched then need to update col2 = col3 if not matched then need to check next row in same table if we didn’t get matching values then we need to update col2 as null or empty

Ex.

```
Insert into table B (col1, col2, col3)
    select col1, col2= 
        (Select col3 from table A where col1 =col3),col3 
    from Table A
```

It is not working because sub query will return multiple values because of select query(col2=select……)

Table A

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | null | 222 |
| 222 | null | 333 |
| 444 | null | 111 |

Table B should be like this col3 value should match witch col1 value in any of the rows in the table and then we have to pick matching col3 value and update in col2. hope this make sense

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 333 | 222 |
| 222 | null | 333 |
| 444 | 222 | 111 |

Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Have you tried using [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html)? Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: `...if values is not found then we need to search next row...` This implies an order by, possibly partitioned somehow. Please provide a minimal sample of source data in addition to the SQL you've tried so far as @Sergiu mentioned.

Comment: if you want to compare only the current values between col1 and col3 then add case statement e.g. ```select col1, case when col1=col3 then col3 end null as col2 ,col3 from Table A

Comment: @GregPavlik i have modified post with example. Please take a look.

Comment: @Sergiu - Please the example table in the post.

Comment: Why does the second row of `col3` change between Table A and Table B? The sample SQL shows just a simple selection of `col3` rather than a transformation. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure of the logic, but you can use an update with a join to reference the value from another table.

```
UPDATE TABLE B
SET B.COL2 = A.COL3
FROM A
WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL3;
```

Of course, this is assuming there are no duplicate values in COL3 ... may need to see more data to fully understand the use case and scenario you're dealing with.